# Redirect the Java output in a Makefile

Tags: java, unix, makefile

I am a new to Makefiles and I am currently writing one. This is what I have so far:

```
cc = gcc
EXE = foo
JAVAC = javac
JRE = java
PAGER = less
TEST_OUT = test.out
EXP_OUT = expected.out

#clean run-py run-c read run-java save-java and test-java are all phony targets.

    foo.o : foo.c foo.h
    $(cc) -c foo.c

main.o: main.c foo.h
    $(cc) -c main.c

$(EXE): foo.o main.out
    $(cc) -o$(EXE) main.o foo.o

run-c: $(EXE)
    ./$(EXE)

run-py: foo.py
    ./foo.py

read:
    $(PAGER)

foo.class: foo.java
    $(JAVAC) foo.java

run-java: foo.class
    $(JRE) foo

save-java: foo.class
    $(JRE) foo > $(TEST_OUT)

test-java: $(TEST_OUT) $(EXP_OUT)
    -@if diff $(TEST_OUT) $(EXP_OUT) &> /dev/null ; then \
    echo "Passed!" ;\
    else \
    echo "Not the same!" ;\
    fi

    clean:
       rm foo.o\
       rm main.o\
       rm $(EXE)\
       rm run-c\
       rm run-py\
       rm foo.class\
       rm rn0java\
       rm save-java\
       rm test\java
```

In the `save-java`, I want to run my Java program, but redirect the output to `$(TEST_OUT)`. How can I achieve this? Also, in one tutorial, I found that someone used `-\rm xxx` in `clean`. Is it any different from simply writing `rm xxx`?

This is the output:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'test.out', needed by 'test-java'.  Stop.`

I guess my redirection is still wrong.

Comment: use `>` to redirect the output and the `-` is used to "silent" `rm` (as far as I remember)

Comment: is it like  " $(JRE) foo > $(TEST_OUT)"

Comment: How are `test.out`, `main.out`, and `expected.out` generated?

Comment: Oh, sorry! That should be main.o. test.out and expected.out are already exist in my folder.

Comment: @user657267 Hi, I just found that I failed to generate the `test.out`.. maybe my redirection is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the fact that I'm not sure what the relationship is between your C and java programs, here's what I think you're trying to do

```
target    := foo
test      := test.out
expected  := expected.out

JAVAC     := javac
JAVAFLAGS :=
JRE       := java

main.o $(target).o: %.o: %.h
$(target): $(target).o main.o

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) $(JAVAFLAGS) $^

$(TEST_OUT): $(target).class
    $(JRE) $< > $@

.PHONY: java-test clean

java-test: $(TEST_OUT) $(EXP_OUT)
    diff -q $^

clean: ; $(RM) $(target).o main.o $(target) $(target).class
```

- `cc` should be a file link to your default compiler (or the compiler itself), you shouldn't need to define it in the makefile. Make sets `CC` to `cc` by default, and uses `CC` in its implicit rule for C source files and linking.
- I don't see any use for a lot of the supposedly `.PHONY` targets you mentioned, also why would you delete them? They aren't files
- Make already knows how to compile C source files, and it'll also link `foo` automatically because one of its prerequisites is `foo.o`.
- `diff` already has a "are these two files the same" flag (`-q`).
- You should have a `.PHONY` target named `all` at the top that executes the default action, but I can't tell what that would be in this case.

Comment: Actually I just finished it, But still thank you very much.